# Orientation-preserving local difeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, orientation, diffeomorphism

I was studying some notes of classes and I am stucked at the following proposition:

> Let $S_1,S_2,S_3$ be orientated surfaces. If $S_1\stackrel{f}{\to}S_2\stackrel{g}{\to}S_3$ are local diffeomorphisms, so $g\circ f$ preservs orientation.

As a sketch of proof, the professor wrote:

> $d(g\circ f)=dg_{f(p)}\circ df_p.$

Well, I could not understand this. For instance, if $f$ preservs orientation and $g$ invertes orientation, so I was thoughting why $g\circ f$ preservs orientation?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct, we need to know more about $f$ and $g$. We can get and easy counterexample taking $S_1=S_2$, $f=id$ and $g$ reversing orientation.

Comment: You're right, many thanks!